# Haskell export current module with additional imported module

Tags: haskell, module, export

Is it possible to write a module in Haskell, which re-exports a module in addition to exporting everything **visible** inside?

Lets consider following module:

```
module Test where
import A

f x = x
```

This module exports everything **defined** inside, so it exports `f` but does not re-export anything imported from `A`.

On the other hand, if I want to re-export the module `A`:

```
module Test (
    module A,
    f
) where
import A

f x = x
```

Is there a way to re-export `A` and export **everything** defined in `Test` without needing to explicitly write every function defined within `Test`?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

There is a simple solution, just export the module from the module:

```
module Test
    ( module Test
    , module A
    ) where

import Prelude()
import A
f x = x
```

Comment: Exploited [here](https://github.com/ndmitchell/tagsoup/commit/1f1fff1e9ce4bd3233a2ef9607287b5018b516a7#diff-430b750c0b6fd0e9461c82565a1345dcR8).

Comment: Also, any insight as to why this works? (Any documentation?)

Comment: @PyRulez The Haskell Report is the definitive source: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1000005.2