# Module export list: how to export imported module?

Tags: haskell

I can re-export imported module like:

```
module My (
  module Another
, A
) where
import Another
```

But this form will export only `Another` and `A`. How to export anything (all!) and imported module without to enumerate all exporting symbols? Something like export without the list:

```
module My where
...
```

PS. The last form does not re-export importing modules. Is it possible at whole?

Comment: duplicate of [Haskell export current module with additional imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035458/haskell-export-current-module-with-additional-imported-module?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
module My (module My, module Another) where
import Another
```

Pretty sneaky, huh?