# Haskell re-export module which only import a selected part of identifiers

Tags: haskell

I know that I can re-export modules like following:

```
module Test (module Test) where

import Prelude as Test
import A as Test

f x = x
```

But now I want to do re-export a partial imported module like

```
module Test (module Test) where

import Prelude (map, filter) as Test
import A as Test

f x = x
```

References:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/42sx3x/haskell_reexport_everything/
- [Haskell export current module with additional imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035458/haskell-export-current-module-with-additional-imported-module/18035699#18035699)

Answer (score 2):

From [Haskell wiki about Import](https://wiki.haskell.org/Import), there is an example like this:

```
import Mod as Foo (x,y)
```

So, do it like this:

```
module Test (module Test) where

import Prelude as Test (map, filter)
import A as Test

f x = x
```